# WebGl memory notation for matrices

Tags: javascript, math, matrix, webgl

Since webGL derives from openGL the coordinate system should be right handed, but as I'm trying to rotate a model by hand-writing the rotation matrix the visual output is the opposite of what I'd expect.

OpenGL needed matrices written in column-major format, and this is the way i'm handwriting a 90° counter-clockwise rotation matrix (assuming we're using a right handed coordinate system) around the y axis:

```
var rot = new glMatrix.ARRAY_TYPE(16);
//I indexed the array this way to edit those values as if I 
were editing rows instead of columns
rot[0]  = 0;
rot[4]  = 0;
rot[8]  = -1;
rot[12] = 0;

rot[1]  = 0;
rot[5]  = 1;
rot[9]  = 0;
rot[13] = 0;

rot[2]  = 1;
rot[6]  = 0;
rot[10] = 0;
rot[14] = 0;

rot[3]  = 0;
rot[7]  = 0;
rot[11] = 0;
rot[15] = 1;
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(Program.model, false, rot);
```

I'd expect a 90° ccw rotation around the y axis but i'm getting a cw one instead. The transpose works as expected which means either the math is wrong or that I'm missing something else

Comment: The native OpenGL coordinate system (NDC = Normalized Device Coordinates) is left-handed. One common approach is to use a right-handed coordinate system to specify your objects, and then flip the handedness of the coordinate system as part of the projection matrix. But with shader based OpenGL, you can handle your coordinate systems any way you want, as long as the output of you vertex shader has the correct orientation.

Comment: If I recall correctly the left-handedness comes into equation just after the projection matrix does its work, and tries to map every vertex into a  unit cube with the depth swapped (instead of pointing to -1 it now points to 1) but this does not explain why the matrix i've written does not work as expected, since all the calculation and model matrix multiplication happens in "world space" which still is right handed before projection multiplication comes in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage is orthogonal to how matrices are used. You can store them column major or row major. How they get used in multiplication is unrelated to their storage.

To make that clear I could store the matrix like this

```
// storage format 1
[xaxis-x, xaxis-y, xaxis-z, 0,
 yaxis-x, yaxis-y, yaxis-z, 0,
 zaxis-x, zazis-y, xaxis-z, 0,
 trans-x, trans-y, trans-z, 1]
```

Or I could store it like this

```
// storage format 2
[xaxis-x, yaxis-x, zaxis-x, trans-x,
 xaxis-y, yaxis-y, zaxis-y, trans-y,
 xaxis-z, yazis-z, zaxis-z, trans-z,
 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I can then write all of these functions

```
columnMajorMutliplyUsingStorageFormat1(matrix, vector)
columnMajorMutliplyUsingStorageFormat2(matrix, vector)
rowMajorMutliplyUsingStorageFormat1(matrix, vector)
rowMajorMutliplyUsingStorageFormat2(matrix, vector)
```

You can imagine how those functions would be written. The point is storage format is separate from usage.

In any case pretty much all WebGL and OpenGL programs a matrix almost always takes storage format 1

```
// storage format 1
[xaxis-x, xaxis-y, xaxis-z, 0,
 yaxis-x, yaxis-y, yaxis-z, 0,
 zaxis-x, zazis-y, xaxis-z, 0,
 trans-x, trans-y, trans-z, 1]
```

You can verify this in OpenGL 1.0.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glTranslatef(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
float mat[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW, &mat[0]);
printf("%f %f %f %f\n", mat[0], mat[1], mat[2], mat[3]);
printf("%f %f %f %f\n", mat[4], mat[5], mat[6], mat[7]);
printf("%f %f %f %f\n", mat[8], mat[9], mat[10], mat[11]);
printf("%f %f %f %f\n", mat[12], mat[13], mat[14], mat[15]);
```

Will print something like

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
1 2 3 1
```

In other words if you want to set the translation set elements 12, 13, 14. If you want to set xaxis set elements 0, 1, 2

Here's the typical example with translation in elements 12, 13, 14

The canonical example of usage would be

```
gl_Position = worldViewProjectionMatrix * position;
```

```js
"use strict";
twgl.setDefaults({attribPrefix: "a_"});
var m4 = twgl.m4;
var gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl")
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);
var bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 2);

var tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  min: gl.NEAREST,
  mag: gl.NEAREST,
  src: [
    255, 255, 255, 255,
    192, 192, 192, 255,
    192, 192, 192, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255,
  ],
    });

    var uniforms = {
    u_lightWorldPos: [1, 8, -10],
  u_lightColor: [0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 1],
  u_ambient: [0, 0, 0, 1],
  u_specular: [1, 1, 1, 1],
  u_shininess: 50,
  u_specularFactor: 1,
  u_diffuse: tex,
};

                             function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  var projection = m4.perspective(30 * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.5, 10);
  var eye = [1, 4, -6];
  var target = [0, 0, 0];
  var up = [0, 1, 0];

  var camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  var view = m4.inverse(camera);
  var viewProjection = m4.multiply(view, projection);
  var world = m4.rotationY(time);

  uniforms.u_viewInverse = camera;
  uniforms.u_world = world;
  uniforms.u_worldInverseTranspose = m4.transpose(m4.inverse(world));
  uniforms.u_worldViewProjection = m4.multiply(world, viewProjection);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
  <script id="vs" type="notjs">
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
uniform vec3 u_lightWorldPos;
uniform mat4 u_world;
uniform mat4 u_viewInverse;
uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTranspose;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToView;

void main() {
  v_texCoord = a_texcoord;
  v_position = (u_worldViewProjection * a_position);
  v_normal = (u_worldInverseTranspose * vec4(a_normal, 0)).xyz;
  v_surfaceToLight = u_lightWorldPos - (u_world * a_position).xyz;
  v_surfaceToView = (u_viewInverse[3] - (u_world * a_position)).xyz;
  gl_Position = v_position;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToView;

uniform vec4 u_lightColor;
uniform vec4 u_ambient;
uniform sampler2D u_diffuse;
uniform vec4 u_specular;
uniform float u_shininess;
uniform float u_specularFactor;

vec4 lit(float l ,float h, float m) {
  return vec4(1.0,
              max(l, 0.0),
              (l > 0.0) ? pow(max(0.0, h), m) : 0.0,
              1.0);
}

void main() {
  vec4 diffuseColor = texture2D(u_diffuse, v_texCoord);
  vec3 a_normal = normalize(v_normal);
  vec3 surfaceToLight = normalize(v_surfaceToLight);
  vec3 surfaceToView = normalize(v_surfaceToView);
  vec3 halfVector = normalize(surfaceToLight + surfaceToView);
  vec4 litR = lit(dot(a_normal, surfaceToLight),
                    dot(a_normal, halfVector), u_shininess);
  vec4 outColor = vec4((
  u_lightColor * (diffuseColor * litR.y + diffuseColor * u_ambient +
                u_specular * litR.z * u_specularFactor)).rgb,
      diffuseColor.a);
  gl_FragColor = outColor;
}
  </script>
  <script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

and here's the opposite example with translation in elements 3, 7, 11

In this case the math in the shader has been changed to

```
gl_Position = position * worldViewProjectionMatrix;
```

```js
"use strict";
twgl.setDefaults({attribPrefix: "a_"});
var m4 = twgl.m4;
var gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl")
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);
var bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 2);

var tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  min: gl.NEAREST,
  mag: gl.NEAREST,
  src: [
    255, 255, 255, 255,
    192, 192, 192, 255,
    192, 192, 192, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255,
  ],
    });

    var uniforms = {
    u_lightWorldPos: [1, 8, -10],
  u_lightColor: [0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 1],
  u_ambient: [0, 0, 0, 1],
  u_specular: [1, 1, 1, 1],
  u_shininess: 50,
  u_specularFactor: 1,
  u_diffuse: tex,
};

                             function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  var projection = m4.perspective(30 * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.5, 10);
  var eye = [1, 4, -6];
  var target = [0, 0, 0];
  var up = [0, 1, 0];

  var camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  var view = m4.inverse(camera);
  var viewProjection = m4.multiply(view, projection);
  var world = m4.rotationY(time);

  uniforms.u_viewInverse = m4.transpose(camera);
  uniforms.u_world = m4.transpose(world);
  uniforms.u_worldInverseTranspose = m4.transpose(m4.transpose(m4.inverse(world)));
  uniforms.u_worldViewProjection = m4.transpose(m4.multiply(world, viewProjection));

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
uniform vec3 u_lightWorldPos;
uniform mat4 u_world;
uniform mat4 u_viewInverse;
uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTranspose;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToView;

void main() {
  v_texCoord = a_texcoord;
  v_position = (a_position * u_worldViewProjection);
  v_normal = (vec4(a_normal, 0) * u_worldInverseTranspose).xyz;
  v_surfaceToLight = u_lightWorldPos - (a_position * u_world).xyz;
  v_surfaceToView = (u_viewInverse[3] - (a_position * u_world)).xyz;
  gl_Position = v_position;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToView;

uniform vec4 u_lightColor;
uniform vec4 u_ambient;
uniform sampler2D u_diffuse;
uniform vec4 u_specular;
uniform float u_shininess;
uniform float u_specularFactor;

vec4 lit(float l ,float h, float m) {
  return vec4(1.0,
              max(l, 0.0),
              (l > 0.0) ? pow(max(0.0, h), m) : 0.0,
              1.0);
}

void main() {
  vec4 diffuseColor = texture2D(u_diffuse, v_texCoord);
  vec3 a_normal = normalize(v_normal);
  vec3 surfaceToLight = normalize(v_surfaceToLight);
  vec3 surfaceToView = normalize(v_surfaceToView);
  vec3 halfVector = normalize(surfaceToLight + surfaceToView);
  vec4 litR = lit(dot(a_normal, surfaceToLight),
                    dot(a_normal, halfVector), u_shininess);
  vec4 outColor = vec4((
  u_lightColor * (diffuseColor * litR.y + diffuseColor * u_ambient +
                u_specular * litR.z * u_specularFactor)).rgb,
      diffuseColor.a);
  gl_FragColor = outColor;
}
  </script>
  <script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: "If you want to set xaxis set elements 0, 1, 2" since that matrix is stored in column major format, to change the x orthonormal basis shouldn't we overwrite the 0, 4, 8 elements? One last question: since I stored the matrix in column major format and i'm multiplying it as in your first example `gl_Position = worldViewProjectionMatrix * position;` the fact that i'm getting the opposite rotation direction could be caused by the fact that the openGL standard assumes a right-handed world space while matrix transformations "assumes a left-handed world-space" ?

Comment: I can't say, how about your matrix multiply functions? Are you creating matrices like everyone else and multiplying them like everyone else? see [glmatrix](http://glmatrix.net/) or [twgl](http://twgljs.org) or even [three.js](http://threejs.org) and make sure you're doing the same things they are. Your rotation matrix is constructed the same way and when you multiply with another matrix you get the same result. Similarly check you're multiplying in the same order in the shader.

Comment: it appears that hand-crafting matrix rotations has to take into account the handedness of the calculation. Use a right-handed system and the rotation will be the opposite of the expected one, webgl had nothing to do with it. We could almost say that at least rotation wise, linear algebra itself is "left-handed"